# How can I make a number picker in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-number-picker

I am trying to make a number picker in jetpack compose just like the below
I searched something about number picker on the internet and I found this

**https://github.com/ChargeMap/Compose-NumberPicker**

I think he did it using a library here, but I couldn't figure out how to add that library if he used a library. Other than that, can I do this using jetpack compose without using a library and how?. Can you give an example?

[image]

Comment: Hey, all steps needed to add this library are included in the link that you have provided.